# How to make this loop asynchronous?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm working with Github API right now, and here's a function that fetches all pull requests for each repo in list:

```
async def get_all_pulls(repos, api):
    pulls = []
    for repo in repos:
        try:
            async for pull in api.getiter(f'/repos/{org}/{repo}/pulls?state=all'):
                pull['repo'] = repo
                if pull not in pulls:
                    pulls.append(pull)
        except Exception:
            print(f"Bad repo/no access=> [{repo}]")
            continue

    return pulls
```

Everything works fine but one little problem, it takes a lot of time because of that iteration over repos(let's say there is 30 of them).

I was trying to make it async like this(sure thing I am getting rid of for loop in declaration when using this):

```
        # gather all prs for all repos

        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get_all_pulls_for_repo(api, repo)) for repo in repos]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        # unwrap list of lists
        for res in results:
            all_pull_requests += res
```

But I get crashes and saying repos are bad etc.
I think I'm missing something important here but can't get what.

Why does it crash with async for loop? And can I make it work?

**UPDATE1**:
Traceback at get_all_reviews:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/metal/Documents/projects/-git/async_git_tool.py", line 193, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/home/metal/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/metal/Documents/projects/-git/async_git_tool.py", line 113, in main
    reviewed = await get_all_reviews(created, api, ss_programmers)
  File "/home/metal/Documents/projects/-git/async_git_tool.py", line 181, in get_all_reviews
    async for review in api.getiter(f'/repos/{org}/{pr_repo}/pulls/{pr_number}/reviews'):
  File "/home/metal/Documents/projects/-git/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gidgethub/abc.py", line 85, in getiter
    data, more = await self._make_request("GET", url, url_vars, b"", accept)
  File "/home/metal/Documents/projects/-git/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gidgethub/abc.py", line 66, in _make_request
    data, self.rate_limit, more = sansio.decipher_response(*response)
  File "/home/metal/Documents/projects/-git/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gidgethub/sansio.py", line 284, in decipher_response
    rate_limit = RateLimit.from_http(headers)
  File "/home/metal/Documents/projects/-git/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gidgethub/sansio.py", line 226, in from_http
    limit = int(headers["x-ratelimit-limit"])
  File "multidict/_multidict.pyx", line 140, in multidict._multidict._Base.__getitem__
  File "multidict/_multidict.pyx", line 135, in multidict._multidict._Base._getone
KeyError: "Key not found: 'x-ratelimit-limit'"
```

Here's the funciton itself:

```
    async def get_all_reviews(pulls, api, programmers):
    reviewed_pulls = []
    for pull in pulls:
        pr_repo = pull['repo']
        pr_number = str(pull['number'])

        async for review in api.getiter(f'/repos/{org}/{pr_repo}/pulls/{pr_number}/reviews'):
            if review['user']['login'] not in programmers \
                    and pull not in reviewed_pulls:
                reviewed_pulls.append(pull)

    return reviewed_pulls
```

and I'm calling it like that:

```
reviewed = await get_all_reviews(softserve_created, api, ss_programmers)
```

Comment: What concrete module you use to work with Github api?

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov I am using _Gidgegethub_(http://gidgethub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

Idea you described worked fine for me:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import gidgethub
from gidgethub.aiohttp import GitHubAPI


# TODO 
# paste your token to have rate limits
# https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/
TOKEN = '...'


async def get_all_pulls_for_repo(gh, org, repo):
    pulls = []
    async for pull in gh.getiter(f'/repos/{org}/{repo}/pulls?state=all'):
        pulls.append(pull)
        await gh.sleep(0.1)  # avoid RateLimitExceeded, you should count it somehow
    return pulls


async def main():
    org = 'brettcannon'
    repos = ['gidgethub', 'caniusepython3', 'importlib_resources']

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        gh = GitHubAPI(session, 'requester', oauth_token=TOKEN)
        tasks = [
            asyncio.ensure_future(get_all_pulls_for_repo(gh, org, repo))
            for repo 
            in repos
        ]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    for res in results:
        for pull in res:
            print(pull['url'])


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

Create token for requests, paste it and you'll see list of PR urls.

Comment: sleep() worked well for eliminating the issue at get_all_pulls, but I still have a traceback at get_all_reviews, please check updated question at the top, thanks.

Comment: plus I've just noticed that if I'm using non-async for repo in repos I'm getting a total of 9983 pull requests and if async - It's only 7k

Comment: @Roman, error you get is not related to your code, it's a bug in gidgethub - https://github.com/brettcannon/gidgethub/issues/25 I think number of PRs you retrieve is also related to how gidgethub works.